# Reading ints from .txt file to vector?

Tags: c++

For some reason I am getting zero values in my vector when I try to read from a txt file.

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    ifstream read("problem13.txt");
    vector<int> source;
    int n;

    while (read >> n){
        source.push_back(n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++)
        cout << source[i];

   cout << "Finished.";

}
```

The txt file is rather long but the format is:
`37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250`
`46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538`
`74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629`
`91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250`
`23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676`

Comment: those numbers are way too big to be stored as `int`s

Comment: @calccrypto I'm trying to read them one digit at a time. I'm not quite sure how to do that with vectors.

Comment: Do you want to store each digit as an `int`?

Comment: maybe instead of `int` use `char`, and then subtract `(char) '0'` from the value. [std::ifstream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) returns an `int`

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, I would like to store each digit as an `int`. I know how to do that as a `char` but I was wondering if vectors (which is a new concept to me) can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Here is reading one by one:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream read("e:\\problem13.txt");
    vector<int> source;
    char n;

    while (read >> n){
        source.push_back(n - '0');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++)
        cout << source[i];

   cout << endl << "Size: " << source.size() << endl << "Finished.";

}
```

But i recommend you reading line by line or if the file is no so big reading all in an std::string and process the string (reading from file is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

In order to store each digit as an int, read each line and store it in a string. Then process each line.

```
int main(){
    ifstream read("problem13.txt");
    vector<int> source;
    int n;
    string line;

    while (read >> line){
        string::iterator iter = line.begin();
        string::iterator end = line.end();
        for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
        {
           n = (*iter) - '0';
           source.push_back(n);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++)
        cout << source[i];

   cout << "Finished.";

}
```

Comment: he said he just learned about vectors. perhaps iterators are a bit premature?